# Failed to connect to www.google.co.in:443 error in burp suite?

Tags: proxy, configuration, burp-suite, tls-intercept

[image: Error Page]

I am trying to intercept the https request, but I getting this error while searching anything in URL.it's hitting my burp, but I can't get any response after clicking forward button,it comes with this error. I did all cofiguration.

Could you someone help me out with this.

Comment: Can you look at Burp's error log (it should flash orange every time it updates) and see what error is there? It will probably be at least a little more informative. Beyond that, can you verify (without going through Burp) that you can load `www.google.com`? Also note the gTLD; your browser (and proxy) are trying to hit google.**com**, not google.**co.in**.

Comment: This issue often occurs on corporate networks where you need a proxy to access the Internet. You need to configure the proxy in Burp in User options > Connections > Upstream Proxy Servers

Comment: @PortSwigger I think you are correct. I am on the corporate network. I don't know how to configure.could you help me out in this?

Comment: Your corporate proxy details would have been in your browser config before your configured Burp. If you've now lost them you'll need to ask a sysadmin. Once you have the details, follow [these instructions](https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/2363078-burp-suite-options-upstream-proxy-servers)